# Expanded element (and molecule) abundance graph?

Tags: big-bang-theory, nucleosynthesis, elemental-abundances

There is the "classical" nucleosynthesis timeline chart where the $\log ({\rm mass \,fraction})$ is plotted as a function of $\log(t)$ where $t$ is in seconds after the big bang, looking e.g. as follows

[image: Nucleosynthesis chart]

[Source](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/%7Ewright/BBNS.html)

I am searching for the same chart reaching out a bit further towards 17 on the $x$-axis (which would be right now) and I am wondering whether such a thing exists (and what would be the appropriate search terms for a knowledge database).

#### References

- [Can you recommend a book about big bang nucleosynthesis and chemical abundances?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20948/37191)
- [XKCD Timeline of the universe explained](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2240:_Timeline_of_the_Universe)

Comment: I can envisage what you mean but I don't believe I've ever seen one. A problem would be that these are universal abundances, but the enrichments that are calculated later due to stars will enrich their local environments so you would have to apply some sort of dilution factor to correct some sort of average galactic chemical evolution model.

Comment: @ProfRob I would already be happy with some local curves without the dilution.

Comment: But then it will be unrelated to nucleisynthesus. Basically you are looking for an averaged distribution of the elements in the Universe, isn't it?